# Табличные функции с зависимостями

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Допустим, есть функция:

```
CREATE FUNCTION T2
(   

)
RETURNS  TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
    (
    SELECT 2 as R1,3 as R2,3 as R3 FROm T1 r
    JOIN T2 r2 on dbo.T2123(r2.Rec_id)=r.Rec_id
    )
GO
```

Эта функция зависит от функции `T2123`.

Так вот, можно ли развернуть эту функцию в тот момент, когда еще не создана функция `T2123`?

Сейчас ругается на то, что отсутствует `T2123`.

Если объявить возвращаемую таблицу явно

```
RETURNS @TMP TABLE(R1 INT,R2 INT,R3 INT)
```

То проблема исчезает. Хотя странно, как она может возникать в первом случае, так как например возвращаемый тип известен.

Это единственное решение, что бы уйти от следования правильному порядок развертывания функций или можно как-то временно отключить проверку объектов?